# linq .Where() issue "Type of condition expression cannot be determined"

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to pass different variables in a Linq query depending on if a string is null.

```
string site = null;
int q = a number;

var data = db.tbl_table12345
             .Where(site == null
                      ? d => d.stuff_id == org 
                             && d.Date.Month == q
                             && d.Date.Year == year 
                             && d.Q1 != (int?)null
                      : d => d.stuff_id == org
                             && d.Service == site
                             && d.Date.Month == q 
                             && d.Date.Year == year
                             && d.Q1 != (int?)null)
             .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
             .Select(d => new
                          {
                              q1 = d.Key,
                              total = d.Count()
                          });
```

So in the above example if `site == null` then we perform a `.Where` search without the `d.Service == site` parameter. Else the service parameter is used in addition to the rest of the query. Is this possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework here? Because if you are, you aren't allowed to use expressions like `d.Date.Month`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add an additional filter to the query when a condition is met then that construct should be outside of the query itself, which LINQ makes quite easy to do:

```
var query = db.tbl_table12345
    .Where(d => d.stuff_id == org
                    && d.Date.Month == q
                    && d.Date.Year == year
                    && d.Q1 != (int?)null);
if (site != null)
    query = query.Where(d => d.Service == site);
var data = query.GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
    .Select(d => new
    {
        q1 = d.Key,
        total = d.Count()
    });
```

Comment: This makes a perfect example on how to utilize LINQ in a readable fashion.

Comment: I am not overly familiar with the SQL LINQ Provider. Is it going to optimize away the second database call from the extra `Where`?

Comment: @Romoku There are *zero* database interactions in the code provided.  The query, in entirety, will be compiled into *one* SQL query *when `data` is actually iterated* and the query will be executed at that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if the ternary operator was "inside" the lambda.

```
string site = null;
int q = a number;

var data = db.tbl_table12345
             .Where(d => site == null 
                    ? d.stuff_id == org 
                      && d.Date.Month == q 
                      && d.Date.Year == year 
                      && d.Q1 != (int?)null 
                    : d.stuff_id == org 
                      && d.Service == site 
                      && d.Date.Month == q 
                      && d.Date.Year == year 
                      && d.Q1 != (int?)null)
             .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
             .Select(d => new 
                    { 
                         q1 = d.Key,
                         total = d.Count() 
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking up the expressions will let you visualize your logic better.

```
string site = null;
int month = a number;

Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> nullExpression =
    d => d.stuff_id == org 
         && SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == month
         && SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", d.Date) == year
         && d.Q1 != (int?)null;

Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> notNullExpression =
    d => d.stuff_id == org
         && SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == month
         && SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", d.Date) == year
         && d.Q1 != (int?)null
         && d.Service == site;

var expression = site == null ? nullExpression : notNullExpression

var data = db.tbl_table12345
             .Where(expression)
             .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
             .Select(d => new { q1 = d.Key, total = d.Count() });
```

Or using Expression trees:

```
var expression = BuildWhere(org, month, year, site);
var data = db.tbl_table12345
         .Where(expression)
         .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
         .Select(d => new { q1 = d.Key, total = d.Count() });
```

And here is a method that will build up your where `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>`.

```
public Expression BuildWhere(int org, int month, int year, string service = null)
{
    var datePartMethod =
        typeof(SqlFunctions)
            .GetMethod("DatePart",
                       new[]
                       {
                           typeof(string),
                           typeof(DateTime?)
                       });

    // Variable d
    var variable =
        Expression.Variable(typeof(SomeType));

    var orgConstant =
        Expression.Constant(org);
    // d.stuff_id
    var stuffId =
        Expression.Property(variable, "stuff_id");

    // d.stuff_id == org
    var stuffIdEquals =
        Expression.Equal(stuffId, orgConstant);

    // d.Date cast into Nullable DateTime
    var date =
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Property(variable, "Date"),
            typeof(DateTime?));

    var monthPartConstant =
        Expression.Constant("MONTH");
    // month cast to nullable int
    var monthConstant =
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Constant(month),
            typeof(int?));
    var yearPartConstant =
        Expression.Constant("YEAR");
    // year cast to nullable int
    var yearConstant =
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Constant(year),
            typeof(int?));

    // SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date)
    var invokeDatePartMonthPart =
        Expression.Call(
            datePartMethod,
            monthPartConstant,
            date);
    // SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", d.Date)
    var invokeDatePartYearPart =
        Expression.Call(
            datePartMethod,
            yearPartConstant,
            date);

    // SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == month
    var dateMonthEquals =
        Expression.Equal(
            invokeDatePartMonthPart,
            monthConstant);

    // SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == year
    var dateYearEquals =
        Expression.Equal(
            invokeDatePartYearPart,
            yearConstant);

    // d.Q1
    var q1 = Expression.Property(variable, "Q1");
    var nullConstant =
        Expression.Constant((int?) null);
    // d.Q1 != (int?) null
    var q1NotEquals =
        Expression.NotEqual(
            q1,
            nullConstant);

    // d.stuff_id == org
    // && SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == month
    // && SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", d.Date) == year
    // && d.Q1 != (int?) null
    var andExpression = 
        Expression.AndAlso(stuffIdEquals,
            Expression.AndAlso(dateMonthEquals,
            Expression.AndAlso(dateYearEquals,
                q1NotEquals)));

    // Add d.Service only when not null
    if(service != null)
    {
        // d.Service
        var serviceConstant =
            Expression.Constant(service);
        var serviceProperty =
            Expression.Property(
                variable,
                "Service");

        // d.Service == service
        var serviceEquals =
            Expression.Equal(
                serviceProperty,
                serviceConstant);

        andExpression =
            Expression.AndAlso(
                andExpression,
                serviceEquals);
    }

    // Creates a lambda to represent the logic
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeType));
    return Expression
        .Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(
            andExpression,
            parameter);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used expressions before, what would the 'SomeType' be?

Comment: `SomeType` is the type of `d`. I did not know what your type is called so I put in a placeholder. Also check back in a few and I will have an expression trees solution.

Comment: I updated the solution with a dynamic where clause builder for you.

Comment: To your edit, why in the world would you spend so much effort building the entire expression manually when you could just use lambdas and have all of that work done for you in a *dramatically* more readable, maintainable, and quicker to develop manor.

Comment: I will admit building the expression tree is a bit overkill, but LINQ does not provide facilities for more readable, maintainable, and quicker to develop runtime expression generation.

Comment: @Romoku It provides *many* alternatives.  My answer is probably the simplest for this specific case.  For more complex problems that cannot be solved using that pattern there are still many dramatically superior options for enabling more and more dynamic pieces of the query before resorting to creating the entirety of the expressions entirely from scratch.  You can look through [other answers of mine about expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1159478+%5Bexpression%5D) to see various strategies for manipulating expressions with different degrees of dynamic content.

Comment: I'm skeptical that EF will do the right thing with your LINQ statements. I tend to avoid passing EF overly complicated expressions if I don't have to.

Comment: @Romoku If you're skeptical then *go try it out for yourself*.  That said, I don't know what you think is "complicated" about my answer.  The only difference between the build expressions between your first solution and mine is that I sometimes apply to `Where` clauses instead of AND-ing together two expressions in one `Where` clause.  That's not exactly complex.  EF has no problem AND-ing together multiple subsequent `Where` classes itself, as you're more than welcome to test out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

```
 .Where(d => site == null 
          ? d.stuff_id == org 
                 && d.Date.Month == q && d.Date.Year == year 
                 && d.Q1 != (int?)null
          : d.stuff_id == org
                 && d.Service == site && d.Date.Month == q 
                 && d.Date.Year == year && d.Q1 != (int?)null)
```

Comment: This behaves differently to what OPs code would achieve if it compiled.

Comment: ...but it didn't compile and as far as we know, site will always be null making the ternary moot. Guessing the OPs real intent isn't something we can really do here.

Answer (score 0):

From the way your code looks, it appears to me that you're using Entity Framework for your query. If so, you aren't allowed things like `d.Date.Month`, since EF doesn't know how to properly translate that into SQL by itself. You need to use the `SqlFunctions` class (specifically the [DatePart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method) in order to get this query working. Using @Servy's solution as a start:

```
var query = db.tbl_table12345
    .Where(d => d.stuff_id == org
             && SqlFunctions.DatePart("MONTH", d.Date) == q
             && SqlFunctions.DatePart("YEAR", d.Date) == year
             && d.Q1 != (int?)null);
if (site != null)
    query = query.Where(d => d.Service == site);

var data = query.GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
    .Select(d => new
    {
        q1 = d.Key,
        total = d.Count()
    });
```

Another good reason to use this approach is that all of the LINQ clauses above (`Where`, `GroupBy`, and `Select`) all employ deferred execution (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx) for a list of deferred vs. immediate executed methods), which means that only one query will be sent to your database for the final `data`, and only when you actually use that variable in some way.